# Sidebar using Bootstrap is incorrectly rendered

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

need your help. How do I render a sidebar using Bootstrap that looks like this?
[Expected sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onSB3.png)

Currently, my sidebar looks like this
[Actual Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30RdP.png)

Below is the code that I used:

```
<div style={{width:'250px'}} className="d-flex flex-column">
    <Tab.Container activeKey={activeKey} onSelect={setActiveKey}>
    <Nav.Item variant="tabs" className="justify-content-center">
        <Nav.Link eventKey={CONVERSATIONS_KEY}>Conversations</Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link eventKey={CONTACTS_KEY}>Contacts</Nav.Link>
    </Nav.Item>
    <Tab.Content className='border-right overflow-auto flex-grow-1'>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey={CONVERSATIONS_KEY}>
            <Conversations />
        </Tab.Pane>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey={CONTACTS_KEY}>
            <Contacts />
        </Tab.Pane>
    </Tab.Content>
    <div className='p-2 border-top border-right small'>
        Your ID: <span className='text-muted'>{id}</span>
    </div>
    </Tab.Container>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) snippet so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think it should work

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab';
import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs';

// I use Sonnet component and I think It might be helpful
import Sonnet from '../../components/Sonnet';

function ControlledTabsExample() {
  const [key, setKey] = useState('home');

  return (
    <Tabs
      id="controlled-tab-example"
      activeKey={key}
      onSelect={(k) => setKey(k)}
      className="mb-3"
    >
      <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
        <Sonnet />
      </Tab>
      <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
        <Sonnet />
      </Tab>
    
    </Tabs>
  );
}

export default ControlledTabsExample;
```

and finally you can see result image, and you can use this link also
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkv3C.png),
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVr9V.png)

and this [link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/).

Comment: I think It's correct

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I'm having trouble importing Sonnet. 

It says 'Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar.js 10:0-45

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../components/Sonnet which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/./

I tried an alternative approach which can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#tabs it doesn't looks exactly the same though. 